# How to create validator in Yii using self created form

Tags: yii

I have some form, with css defined and with some textfields, let's use the following as example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css"/>
<form action="/em/call" class="myStyle">
field1:<input text="hello"></input>
<input value="submit" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Is it possible to show validation error if field1 is non-empty using Yii built-in validator, if yes, how should I do that?

(In the example given by Yii, it seems using `CWidget::form`, i am not sure how to customized that in my project, where GUI has been defined)

Answer (score 0):

Yii's validators are built for Yii's architecture and thus you always need at least a model that contains your form data. Before you try to hack your way through something i'd suggest to rewrite your form. It's pretty straightforward and it's documented here:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.overview